# How to use padding in div correctly?

Tags: html, css

I’m trying to use padding in a div and which is wrapped by another div (‘container’), apologize for this simple question, but I couldn’t find an answer.

As long as I don’t use `padding:10px;` the structure of the page is stable.
i.e. the right div is floating to the left (‘content’ is aside ‘sidebar’).

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.container {
max-width: 960px;
background-color: RED;
height: 200px;}

.sidebar {
background-color: GREEN;
width: 30%;
float: left;}

.content {
background-color: YELLOW;
float: left;
width: 70%;
padding: 10px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">
    <p>text in sidebar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <p>text in content</p>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

When using `padding:10px;` the right div (‘content’) goes down under ‘sidebar’ instead floating to the side of ‘sidebar’.

I’ve tried `clear: left;` (right, both) but it doesn’t help me.

Any solution for the above and which is not particular style to `<p>` ,would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to avoid going over 100% of the page width and bumping `.content` down, you may have to make some compromises. I can think of a few solutions:

### 1) Pad all direct children of `.content`

```
.content > * {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

​

### 2) Pad `.content` using percentage

```
.content {
    padding-left:2%;
    width:68%;
}
```

### 3) Change the behavior of the box model

```
.content {
     box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
     -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;         
}
```

All three of these solutions incur some *bad* things.

1. Padding all the direct children of `.content` could cause problems down the line when you want to give an element padding other than 10px.
2. Padding `.content` using percentage will look slightly different on different sized windows.
3. Changing the behavior of the box model can be bad if you don't know what you are doing because it alters the default, standard CSS model to one that is not widely used (in this example, we're basically telling modern browsers to use IEs quirksmode box model), but it seems like the best solution for your case. There are basically no issues with it, other than lack of support in IE7, which only has around 2% of browser market share.

Comment: I would be carefull with the * selector, as it is an expensive one. Consider putting an extra div inside your content, .content-inner for example, and giving that a padding of 10px.

Comment: thanks all for your answers, due to the compatibility issues mentioned above, I’m using Cypress solution.

Comment: After reading more about box-sizing. I would recommend going that route. IE7 is the only one that doesn't support it, and as of May 2012, estimates of IE7's global market share were 1.5-5% Basically, people aren't using IE7.

Answer (score 1):

That behaviour is totally correct. Please remember the so-called box model (in short):

> margin, border and padding will all be added to the width value

In this case you have to calculate

```
30% + 10px + 70% + 10px = 100% + 20px
```

---

Browsers start supporting the css property `box-sizing` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing for more information). You can set it to `border-box` in order to change the default box model.

But remember to use those browser suffixes, too:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem, with typical web design not behaving the way our common logic would expect.

What is happening is the padding is actually making the `.content` div become wider than its allocated slot, thus forcing it down underneath.

There's a few ways around this.

This rule: `box-sizing:border-box;` makes it so that if you set `width:100px` and `padding:10px;`, the browser automatically makes the whole DIV 100px no matter what.

What in effect is happening is the DIV is becoming 80px wide, with 10px padding either side.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/Rtwv6/2/)

The browser support for this rule is generally very good, although make sure to include all the rules I've added in the js (I.e, the one with, -webkit-, -moz-, and the one above which is just `box-sizing:border-box;`)

For reference, all the rules here:

```
 box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
```

Comment: be carefull with browser compatibility if you use this. We developers are used to decent browsers, but the majority of users stil work with (old versions of) IE. I would go for the solution @cypressFrankenfeld offered!

Comment: [Compatibility is pretty good](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)
If you're supporting IE 7, then use the manual mode of making the width of the DIV the width you want, minus the padding * 2.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers (to date 10sep2020) concentrate on the fact that adding the padding to the .content **DIV** makes it larger than the required 70% causing it to be pushed under the .sidebar **DIV** and then trying to get the **DIV** size to be 70% including the padding. The simplest answer is to NOT pad the .content **DIV** (so it stays at 70% of the .container **DIV**) but to pad the **P** inside it. Without a width specification, the inner **P** is 100% of the **DIV** INCLUDING the padding thus the text of the **P** will compress accordingly (to 100% of the .content **DIV** - 10px on each side). So change

```
.content {
background-color: YELLOW;
float: left;
width: 70%;
padding: 10px;}
```

to

```
.content {
background-color: YELLOW;
float: left;
width: 70%;}

.content p {
padding: 10px;}
```

Alternatively, adding `box-sizing: border-box` to the .content style changes the size calculation to include the padding but this is CSS3 while moving the padding into the **P** works in earlier versions. (Is anybody is still using it?)

Having tested this, I just have one (rhetorical) question. Why float both **DIV**s? If you only float the .sidebar **DIV** then extra text in the .content **DIV** will flow under it (and the width is now from the left edge of the .container **DIV**). By floating both, the extra text in the .content **DIV** stays to the right leaving a blank area under the .sidebar **DIV** (if it has less in it than the .content **DIV**). I assume that this is the intent but this is exactly the same effect that would result from using a 2 column table,

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.table_container {
width: 100%;
max-width: 960px;
background-color: RED;}

.table_sidebar {
background-color: GREEN;
width: 30%;}

.table_content {
background-color: YELLOW;
width: 70%; /* unnecessary */
padding : 10px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="table_container">
<tr>
<td class="table_sidebar">text in sidebar</td>
<td class="table_content">text in content</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This does have a few slight differences from the original (floating **DIV**) solution.

1. There is a slight gap around each cell.

   The sidebar is the same height as the content.

   The table is only as high as its content (possibly less than the 200px specified).

   The content of the **TD**s has no upper or lower margin (default CSS for a **P** in a **DIV**).

These can be fixed as follows:

1. Add `border-spacing:0` to `.table_container` and (for older browsers) `cellspacing="0"` as an attribute of the **TABLE**.
2. Add `rowspan="2"` to the content **TD**, add an empty **TD** below the sidebar **TD** and force the sidebar **TD** to be as low as possible by adding `height:1px` to `.table_sidebar`.
3. Enclose the table in a **DIV** of the required height.
4. Add **P** elements with specifically defined upper and lower margins in the **TD**s (default CSS for **P** in **TD** apparently has no margins).

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.container {
max-width: 960px;
background-color: RED;
height: 200px;}

.table_container {
width: 100%;
background-color: RED;
border-spacing: 0;}

.table_sidebar {
background-color: GREEN;
width: 30%;
height: 1px;}

.table_content {
background-color: YELLOW;
/* width: 70%; still unnecessary */ 
padding : 10px;}

td p {
margin: 1em 0;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<table class="table_container" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td class="table_sidebar"><p>text in sidebar</p></td>
<td rowspan="2" class="table_content"><p>text in content</p></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

While both methods produce the same output, the **TABLE** method is much less dependent upon getting sizes *just right*.